# How to get the farthest element from the targeted selector

Tags: javascript

The following process works for me, in regards to finding the correct parent. It is out of my control on the duplicated class names as shown below. But is there a shorter way to write the following in raw JavaScript?

```js
var mvalues = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='undefinedundefined']");
mvalues.forEach((item) => {

//is there a shorter way to write this?
item.closest(".input-group").closest(".combobox-container").closest(".input-group").closest(".combobox-container").remove();

});
```

The html looks like this...

```html
<div class="combobox-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="combobox-container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="itemundefinedundefined"></span>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your html

Comment: What's the parent element to the outermost `combobox-container`? Could possibly use a direct child selector.

Comment: its bootstrap class="col-3", thats it.

Comment: Perhaps if you demonstrated the complexity in this or explained why it is necessary (as opposed to, say, adding an ID or more clear class to your target element, people would be less apt to downvote. As it is, it feels like like the standard "I don't like typing; show me a trick where I don't have to type so much" kind of question.

Comment: You could skip the first closest if you know that undefined undefined is not a combobox-container.  There is no such thing as reverse css selectors afaik.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I apologize for any lack of clarity, but the complexity in my response is directly connected to things I'm unable to do (as I originally mentioned), such as adding an ID to the element.  But! I do have control interacting with the original source. This is my first time man-handling closest elements in this type of setup.  Hopefully with that, my demonstration is not too cloudy.

Comment: @klewis ... In your case, the class-name which is the one contributing to the bloated markup you're encountering and thus, the most relevant and therefore too the one to stick to is `combobox-container` ... because of that the expression could be simplified to ... `item.closest(".combobox-container").closest(".combobox-container").remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of Paulo's `$.fn.parents()` solution as a jQuery plugin:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.farthest = function(selector) {
    return this.parents(selector).last();
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#itemundefinedundefined')
  .farthest('.combobox-container')
  .remove(); // Removed "Foo"
```

```css
.combobox-container {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="combobox-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="combobox-container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="itemundefinedundefined">Foo</span>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="combobox-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="combobox-container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="keep-me">Bar</span>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

### Original response

Alternatively, you could use the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector.

Keep in mind that this is relatively newer.

```js
const mVals = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='undefinedundefined']");

// Remove all .col-3 that match
mVals.forEach((el) => {
  el.closest('.col-3:has(.combobox-container)').remove();

  // OR...
  // el.closest('.col-3 > .combobox-container:has(.input-group)')?.parentElement.remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="combobox-container">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="combobox-container">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span id="itemundefinedundefined">FOO</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="combobox-container">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="combobox-container">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span id="item-keep">BAR</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the parent column:

```js
// Remove .combobox-container
mVals.forEach((el) => {
  el.closest('.col-3 > .combobox-container:has(.input-group)').remove();
});
```

Comment: ...or just `document.querySelectorAll('.combobox-container:has(.input-group .combobox-container .input-group [id*="undefinedundefined"])').forEach(e => e.remove())`

Comment: @InSync that would only remove the `<span>` element, not the entire DOM hierarchy.

Comment: Oops, typo. I meant to use `:has()`.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple options on tackling this beast.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `span` really is using an id and not a class, and assuming the structure of your HTML is consistent and something like this:

```
<div class="combobox-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="combobox-container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="itemundefinedundefined">Part of the thing that you want to remove</span>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="combobox-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="combobox-container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="anotherId">something else</span>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You could write the JS shorter in this way:

```
var myItem = document.getElementById("itemundefinedundefined");
myItem.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
```

or even shorter:

```
var myItem = document.getElementById("itemundefinedundefined");
myItem.closest(".combobox-container").remove();
```

It just depends on what limitations you're running into (which parts of the code you can control vs what you cannot).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want the farthest element matching the selector. jQuery offers closest, but not farthest. But it's simple to do it on your own: get all the parents, select the last.

```js
const getFarthest = ( $el, selector ) => {
 return $el.parents(selector).last();
}

const $el = $('#itemundefinedundefined');
const $farthest = getFarthest($el, '.combobox-container');

$farthest.css('border-color', 'red')
```

```css
.combobox-container {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="combobox-container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="combobox-container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="itemundefinedundefined"></span>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know how to word my original question, but you said what I was trying to say in my post, which is why I probably didn't get a welcoming response.  Thank you for saying what I was trying to say! I'll give this a test on my end shortly.  Many thanks friend!